# Поменять текст кнопок регистрации и логина в joomla2.5 + VM2

Tags: joomla

Как поменять текст у кнопок "ВОЙТИ" и "РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ" на свой?
Искал в файле локализации, но там не меняет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открыть language/ru-RU/ru-RU.ini

**Обновление**

Найти файл `ru-RU.ini` в папке `ваш_сайт/language/ru-RU/` , открыть его с помощью текстового редактора, там есть такие строки:

```
JLOGIN="Войти" 
JREGISTER="Регистрация"
```

Поменять их на то, что нужно.